# Android Contacts Fields

Tags: android, field, contacts, contactscontract

I want to have all of the contact's fields but i don't know which class of Contacts Contract do that.

By this code i receive email address:

```
Cursor email = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

This code is used for each field but i need all fields at once, for example:

> Phone - Email - Group Member ship - Identity - Nickname - Organization
>   and etc.

How can i get all of these records at once?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can loop through your contacts and simply get the name and phone number like this:

```
Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

while(people.moveToNext()) {
   int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
   String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
   int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER);
   String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);
}

people.close();
```